# Printing Pattern using Loops

Tags: c, loops

I am solving a challenge on hackerrank. It's printing a number in spiral pattern decreasing it's value at each circle completion.

4 4 4 4 4 4 4
   4 3 3 3 3 3 4
   4 3 2 2 2 3 4
   4 3 2 1 2 3 4
   4 3 2 2 2 3 4
   4 3 3 3 3 3 4
   4 4 4 4 4 4 4

```
//Printing Pattern using Loops
/* for eg. for n = 4 
  4 4 4 4 4 4 4
  4 3 3 3 3 3 4
  4 3 2 2 2 3 4
  4 3 2 1 2 3 4
  4 3 2 2 2 3 4
  4 3 3 3 3 3 4
  4 4 4 4 4 4 4
 */
 //Author: Arvind Bakshi
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{

int n,row,col,size;
scanf("%d", &n);
// Complete the code to print the pattern.
size=2*n-1;
  int arr[size][size];
  //n=n+1;
    while(n>0){
        row=0;
        col=0;
        while(col<size){
          arr[row][col] = n;
          col++;
        }
        col=size-1;
        row=0;
        while(row<size){
            arr[row][col]=n;
            row++;
        }
        row = size-1;
        col = size-1;
        while (col >=0) {
          arr[row][col] = n;
          col--;
        }
        col = 0;
        row = size-1;
        while (row >=0) {
          arr[row][col] = n;
          row--;
        }
        n--;
    }
    for(row=0;row<size;row++){
        for(col=0;col<size;col++){
            printf("%d",arr[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Expected output is

```
 2 2 2 
 2 1 2 
 2 2 2
```

I am getting

```
111
101
111
```

There is numerous code available for it online, I just want to know my mistake, where I am doing wrong. Please don't mark it as a repeat.

Comment: What is the input that you are getting? i.e the value of 'n'.

Comment: Input is any number between 1 and 1000.

Comment: What does it signify?

Comment: for n = 5 and n = 7 it fails after adding +1 to printf. Please don't suggest hardcoding. It must work for 1<n<1000.

Comment: What is your input when you are expecting output from your question?

Comment: You are just decrementing the 'n' value and assigning it to the outer loop on every cycle. The row and column counter are not decrementing. The middle values are garbage values.

Comment: @Santosh - row and col values are changing. please see. After 1 complete spiral sweep the value of n changes. I am going from left->right->bottom->left->top in 1 spiral sweep, decreasing the value of n and repeating the spiral.

Comment: @DevilaN - input is taken in variable n. 1<n<1000.

Comment: Here a refined version - https://github.com/abcool/C_training/blob/Hackerrank-C_Practice/pattern_printing_loops

Comment: Since it's not actually a spiral pattern, you don't need the array or all those `while` loops. You could do it with just those two `for` loops

Comment: @chris turner - how?

Comment: @ArvindBakshi: So you input any number between 1 and 1000 and you got your expected output (3x3 square with 1s and 2s)?

Comment: If I told you how, that would defeat the point of the challenge - you're meant to be solving this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code.
[Online compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/S1th-snM4)
I used your same code with an extra buffer 'x'. This makes the frame to move across the loop in decreasing spiral.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  int n,row,col,size;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  // Complete the code to print the pattern.
  size=2*n;
  int x = n;
  int arr[size-1][size-1];
  //n=n+1;
  while(n>0){
    row=x-n;
    col=x-n;
    while(col<size-(x-n)-2){
      arr[row][col] = n;
      col++;
    }
    col=size-(x-n)-2;
    row=x-n;
    while(row<size-(x-n)-1){
      arr[row][col]=n;
      row++;
    }
    row = size-(x-n)-2;
    col = size-(x-n)-2;
    while (col >x-n) {
      arr[row][col] = n;
      col--;
    }
    col = x-n;
    row = size-(x-n)-2;
    while (row > x-n) {
      arr[row][col] = n;
      row--;
    }
    n--;
  }
  for(row=0;row<size-1;row++){
    for(col=0;col<size-1;col++){
      printf("%d ",arr[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

These are your expected outputs.
[image: for input 2]
[image: for input 4]

Comment: No it works. All you need is a screen to view (100*2)-1=199 number in a single line.

Comment: For such number, forward the output to a text file. With word Warp unchecked, you can view it.

Comment: see I have uploaded a cleaner code but ur logic is not working with it.

Comment: Dude. you are repeating the same thing. You are decrementing the n value and changing only the outer loop.

Comment: what's the purpose of using x?

Comment: x is to the decrement the spiral frame. Do you understand the concept?

Comment: for that I had used n--.

Comment: inside while loop is the whole 1 complete rotation clockwise and n-- repaets it shrinking the frame size. so why x?

Comment: yeah... u are reducing only the 'n' value,this doesn't decreased not the row or column count...also it doesn't reduces the frame size. please understand...
To reduce the row and column count, I used 'x-n' everytime.

Comment: just see the difference by running both the codes, to understand step-by-step compilation process, use turbo c compiler(F7).

Comment: I am using minGW.

Comment: @santosh- while I was comparing to begin array index 0 you replaced it by x-n. Also u added size-(x-n) to conditions. Also you are storing initial value of n in x. Still x-n is confusing.

Comment: I'm using (x-n) as buffer that changes in every loop. for example, take input as 4-> you need to start from 0,0(x-n is 0), for the second time you need to start from 1,1(now x-n is 1). If you begin index with 0, your frame rotates only on the outer loop. That's why im using varying x-n. this make frame to rotate to the inner loop on every cycle.

Comment: @Santosh- https://github.com/abcool/C_training/blob/Hackerrank-C_Practice/digit_freq

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i = n; i >= 1; i--){
        for(int j = n; j > i; j--)
            printf("%d ", j);
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++)
            printf("%d ", i);
        for(int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
            printf("%d ", j);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = n; j > i; j--)
            printf("%d ", j);
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++)
            printf("%d ", i + 1);
        for(int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
            printf("%d ", j);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance and "overwriting" doesn't matter, you can try this intuitive short version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  int n, size;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  size=2*n-1;
  int arr[size][size];

  for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
      for(int row=i; row<size-i; row++)
          for(int col=i; col<size-i; col++)
            arr[row][col] = n-i;

  for(int row=0; row<size; row++) {
    for(int col=0; col<size; col++)
      printf("%d ",arr[row][col]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 1; i<n*2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<n*2; j++)
        {
            int a = i, b = j;
            if(a>n) a = n*2-a;
            if(b>n) b = n*2-b;
            a = (a<b)? a:b;
            printf("%d ",n-a+1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).